# How can I make this custom-filter script "smart"?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I've made a hiking/camping type gear list in Google sheets and use a script to create a menu item that let's me hide rows not associated with a given trip type, e.g.,
[image: Gear list screenshot]

However, in order to create each Trip menu item, I've been manually adding lines to perform the task. I'm realizing now since there is a lot of repeat code I could probably create a function to call to simplify the code, but my main question is - **how would I go about not having to update the script, so that the script would automatically generate a new menu item each time I added a new trip type column, or moved the trip type columns elsewhere in the spreadsheet?**

Perhaps I could append the trip type names with "T-" so a script could find them, but I'm unsure what the next steps would be - any help is appreciated. Current script code is below.

```
//@OnlyCurrentDoc

function showAllRows() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName("Gear");
  sheet.showRows(1, sheet.getMaxRows());
}

function filterHidePacked() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName("Gear");
  var data = sheet.getDataRange().getValues();
  for(var i = 1; i < data.length; i++) {
    //If column A (1st column) is "True" then hide the row.
    if(data[i][0] === "Y") {
      sheet.hideRows(i + 1);
    }
  }
}

function filterShowPacked() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName("Gear");
  var data = sheet.getDataRange().getValues();
  for(var i = 1; i < data.length; i++) {
    //If column A (1st column) is "True" then hide the row.
    if(data[i][0] === "Y" || data[i][0] === "N") {
      sheet.showRows(i + 1);
    }
  }
}

function filterSoloBackpack() {
  showAllRows();
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName("Gear");
  var data = sheet.getDataRange().getValues();
  for(var i = 1; i < data.length; i++) {
    //If column A (1st column) is "True" then hide the row.
    if(data[i][2] === "N") {
      sheet.hideRows(i + 1);
    }
  }
}

function filterBABackpack() {
  showAllRows();
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName("Gear");
  var data = sheet.getDataRange().getValues();
  for(var i = 1; i < data.length; i++) {
    //If column A (1st column) is "True" then hide the row.
    if(data[i][3] === "N") {
      sheet.hideRows(i + 1);
    }
  }
}

function filterFamilyCamp() {
  showAllRows();
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName("Gear");
  var data = sheet.getDataRange().getValues();
  for(var i = 1; i < data.length; i++) {
    //If column A (1st column) is "True" then hide the row.
    if(data[i][4] === "N") {
      sheet.hideRows(i + 1);
    }
  }
}

function filterFamilyBackpack() {
  showAllRows();
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName("Gear");
  var data = sheet.getDataRange().getValues();
  for(var i = 1; i < data.length; i++) {
    //If column A (1st column) is "True" then hide the row.
    if(data[i][5] === "N") {
      sheet.hideRows(i + 1);
    }
  }
}

function filterDuoCarCamp() {
  showAllRows();
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName("Gear");
  var data = sheet.getDataRange().getValues();
  for(var i = 1; i < data.length; i++) {
    //If column A (1st column) is "True" then hide the row.
    if(data[i][6] === "N") {
      sheet.hideRows(i + 1);
    }
  }
}

function filterFloatTrip() {
  showAllRows();
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName("Gear");
  var data = sheet.getDataRange().getValues();
  for(var i = 1; i < data.length; i++) {
    //If column A (1st column) is "True" then hide the row.
    if(data[i][7] === "N") {
      sheet.hideRows(i + 1);
    }
  }
}

function filterMtStHelens() {
  showAllRows();
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName("Gear");
  var data = sheet.getDataRange().getValues();
  for(var i = 1; i < data.length; i++) {
    //If column A (1st column) is "True" then hide the row.
    if(data[i][8] === "N") {
      sheet.hideRows(i + 1);
    }
  }
}

function filterSARUrban() {
  showAllRows();
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName("Gear");
  var data = sheet.getDataRange().getValues();
  for(var i = 1; i < data.length; i++) {
    //If column A (1st column) is "True" then hide the row.
    if(data[i][9] === "N") {
      sheet.hideRows(i + 1);
    }
  }
}

function filterSAR24Hr() {
  showAllRows();
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName("Gear");
  var data = sheet.getDataRange().getValues();
  for(var i = 1; i < data.length; i++) {
    //If column A (1st column) is "True" then hide the row.
    if(data[i][10] === "N") {
      sheet.hideRows(i + 1);
    }
  }
}

function filterSAR48Hr() {
  showAllRows();
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName("Gear");
  var data = sheet.getDataRange().getValues();
  for(var i = 1; i < data.length; i++) {
    //If column A (1st column) is "True" then hide the row.
    if(data[i][11] === "N") {
      sheet.hideRows(i + 1);
    }
  }
}

function onOpen() {
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().createMenu("Trip")
    .addItem("Hide Packed", "filterHidePacked")
    .addItem("Show Packed", "filterShowPacked")
    .addItem("Show All", "showAllRows")
    .addSubMenu(SpreadsheetApp.getUi().createMenu('Trip')
        .addItem('Solo Backpack', 'filterSoloBackpack')
        .addItem('B&A Backpack', 'filterBABackpack')
        .addItem('Family Camp', 'filterFamilyCamp')
        .addItem('Family Backpack', 'filterFamilyBackpack')
        .addItem('Duo Car Camp', 'filterDuoCarCamp')
        .addItem('Float Trip', 'filterFloatTrip')
        .addItem('Mt. St. Helens', 'filterMtStHelens')
        .addItem('SAR Urban', 'filterSARUrban')
        .addItem('SAR 24 Hr.', 'filterSAR24Hr')
        .addItem('SAR 48 Hr.', 'filterSAR48Hr')
        )
    .addToUi();
}
```

Comment: Your title says `How can I make this custom-filter script "smart"?`. But, from `how would I go about not having to update the script, so that the script would automatically generate a new menu item each time I added a new trip type column, or moved the trip type columns elsewhere in the spreadsheet?`, you want to achieve your goal without changing your showing script. Is my understanding correct? First, I would like to correctly understand your question.

Comment: What does making it smart mean to you?

Comment: @Tanaike I am totally up for rewriting the script! When I add a new trip type column, I have to currently manually go into the script and add it as an item (copy/paste, update the column reference). I'd rather not have to go into the script after adding a new trip type column, if that makes sense?

Answer (score 0):

this makes no sense to me:

```
function filterShowPacked() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName("Gear");
  var data = sheet.getDataRange().getValues();
  for(var i = 1; i < data.length; i++) {
    //If column A (1st column) is "True" then hide the row.
    if(data[i][0] === "Y" || data[i][0] === "N") {
      sheet.showRows(i + 1);
    }
  }
}
```

The code does not agree with the comment and it would just show all of the rows.

Comment: You're right - not a function I used much obviously! But that's what it's doing. Good catch, thanks.